# How to detect in runtime if some Compiler Option (like Assertions) was set to ON?

Tags: delphi, runtime, assert, conditional-compilation

What is the conditional to check if assertions are active in Delphi?

I would like to be able to do something to suppress hints about unused variables when assertions are not active in code like

```
procedure Whatever;
var
   v : Integer;
begin
   v := DoSomething;
   Assert(v >= 0);
end;
```

In the above code, when assertions are not active, there is a hint about variable v being assigned a value that is never used.

The code is in a library which is going to be used in various environments, so I'd be able to test for assertions specifically, and not a custom conditional like DEBUG.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this using the [`$IFOPT`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IFOPT_directive_%28Delphi%29) directive:

```
{$IFOPT C+}
  // this block conditionally compiled if and only if assertions are active
{$ENDIF}
```

So you could re-write your code like this:

```
procedure Whatever;
{$IFOPT C+}
var
   v : Integer;
{$ENDIF}
begin
   {$IFOPT C+}v := {$ENDIF}DoSomething;
   {$IFOPT C+}Assert(v >= 0);{$ENDIF}
end;
```

This will suppress the compiler hint, but it also makes your eyes bleed.

I would probably suppress it like this:

```
procedure SuppressH2077ValueAssignedToVariableNeverUsed(const X); inline;
begin
end;

procedure Whatever;
var
   v : Integer;
begin
   v := DoSomething;
   Assert(v >= 0);
   SuppressH2077ValueAssignedToVariableNeverUsed(v);
end;
```

The untyped parameter that the suppress function receives is sufficient to suppress H2077. And the use of `inline` means that the compiler emits no code since there is no function call.

Comment: +1 and lol for the name of your `suppress...` method. Great way of suppressing those hints. Much better than adding a comment to some arbitrary statement that serves the same purpose.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Yes, I tend to favour code that obviates the need for comments.

Comment: Nice trick! I had tried wrapping the Assert in an inline function (that got optimized away as well), but the hint was still there, with yours it's gone!

Comment: @EricGrange Thanks. What would be really nice would be if we could have some fine grained control with compiler directives. Like `{$SUPPRESSHINTS v}` or some such.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: So do I, but method calls can be a burden in highly performant code. Inlining a method that doesn't do anything, would thus always be inlined and be optimised away, just hadn't occurred to me (or any of us at work).

Comment: @MarjanVenema I only had the idea an hour ago right after I cleared the bleeding away!